# 3m Lead Test negative for days then turned positive?

Tags: lead

I tested some dust for lead using a 3m lead check swab. The test was negative, and I left the testing fluid on the surface for several days because I hadn't gotten a chance to clean it up. I know it was orange minutes after testing, and also orange a couple days after testing. It's maybe a week after testing now and I just found that it has turned pink. Does this mean lead is present?

Answer (score 1):

The [3M site says this](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/building-construction-us/resources/news-and-articles/full-story/~/3m-leadcheck-epa-compliance/?storyid=65e7d9db-1412-4f45-ab62-915df7c99e76)

> 3M™ LeadCheck™ Swabs have no shelf life. Unless the ampoules/vials are cracked, they will have an indefinite shelf life.

In other words, once the vial is broken (which you did to use the tester), it does indeed have a shelf life

Comment: I agree, if the op is concerned scuff the surface a bit deeper and retest with a fresh kit, their may be 2 or more layers of lead free paint on top depending on the age of the home and how often it was painted.+

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, it probably means the fluid has oxidized over time.

Answer (score 0):

The fluid is only good for 30 seconds. After that, whatever is says is meaningless.